# replace 0 with NA without changing the class

Tags: r, vector, na

Is there a way to replace 0 with NA where we have `asd$b == "b"` without changing the class of asd

```
> asd <- data.frame(a = c(1,0,0), b = c("a","b","c"))
> asd
  a b
1 1 a
2 0 b
3 0 c
```

I tried below, but failed

```
asd$a <- ifelse(asd$a[asd$b == "b"] == 0, "NA", asd$a[asd$b == "b"])
```

Expected output

```
> asd
  a   b
1 1   a
2 NA  b
3 0   c
```

Still the class of Expected output should be numeric

Comment: Remove the quotes around NA.

Answer (score 6):

Quoted `"NA"` is different from `NA`.

`"NA"` is a character and R will coerce the column the character if you assign that value while `NA` is a missing value indicator.

All previous answers are correct, I just try to give a reason why the coercement.

Answer (score 2):

#### `base` solution

```
asd$a[asd$a == 0 & asd$b == "b"] <- NA

#    a b
# 1  1 a
# 2 NA b
# 3  0 c
```

---

#### `dplyr` solution

```
asd %>% mutate(a = if_else(b == "b", na_if(a, 0), a))
```

or

```
asd %>% mutate(a = if_else(a == 0 & b == "b", NA_real_, a))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an `ifelse` statement, try this solution

```
asd$a <- ifelse(asd$a == 0 & asd$b == "b", NA, asd$a)
```

The problem is that you inserted quoted `"NA"` which is just a simple string and therefore variable `a` is coerced to character. You should instead use unquoted `NA` which indicates a missing value.

---

Example

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c(1,0,0), b = c("a","b","c"))
str(asd)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a: num  1 0 0
#  $ b: chr  "a" "b" "c"

asd$a <- ifelse(asd$a == 0 & asd$b == "b", NA, asd$a)
str(asd)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a: num  1 NA 0
#  $ b: chr  "a" "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dplyr`:

```r
asd %>%
  mutate(a = ifelse(b == "b", na_if(a,0), a))
```

which gives you

```r
   a b
1  1 a
2 NA b
3  0 c
```